# Difficulty creating CSS vertical grid in Bootstrap 3

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

student working on my final project.

I am using Bootstrap 3 and am attempting to build a grid with similar structure to this image below:

[image]

I am only successful making the grids span horizontally %100 thus far.

You can [view](http://www.hardcoded.ca/cp/html/registry.html) my project to see what I have done.

I have attempted creating the following class but have since commented it out in my CSS due to some whacky effects and removed the body positioning.

```
body {
    position: relative;
}
.fluid-height {
    height: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try setting a height of 100vh to your fluid-height div:

```
.fluid-height { height:100vh }
```

You can also use vh with your top grids and equal it all out to 100:

```
.buffer-p { height:10vh; }
.fluid-height { height:90vh; }
```

I don't know your requirements, though vh has some [caveats](http://caniuse.com/#feat=viewport-units) it's fairly safe to use it at this point. If you're concerned about support and your class has reached into the Javascript realm already, you can always set up a quick fallback as mentioned in an answer in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21624014/css-are-view-height-vh-and-view-width-vw-units-widely-supported).

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this with Bootstrap by giving heights to your first and last `row`'s. You can use `vh` for your heights as outlined in this [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/1o3s776s/2/).

You could use static heights for your `row`'s but it wouldn't be responsive. If you use % then you would have to set `html, body { min-height 100%; }` but the heights of your `row`'s would change when content gets added and the page grows.

Answer (score 0):

You can use absolute to both of the classes and give top as well bottom 0px to each class . Based on your design i have made some adjustment.

```
.bg-black {
  background: #000000;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0px;
  top: 269px;
}
    .bg-white {
  background: #FFFFFF;
  left: 25%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 269px;
  bottom: 0px;
}
```