# displaying div tag a percentage height of the window using viewport height (vh) in Wordpress

Tags: html, css, wordpress, responsive-design

[this is how it should look](http://insitu-app.com/iframe.html) but when I paste the same code:

```
    <!-- dummy div -->
    <div style="height:100px;">
    </div>

    <!-- outer div to contain inner div (that has a margin) -->
    <div style="height:80vh;">

   <!-- inner most div now has its boundary defined by the outer div, so adding a border wont extend its width beyond the width of the browser window -->
   <div style="height:80vh; padding: 20px;">

   <!-- iframe set to fill 100% of its containing div -->
   <iframe src="http://insitu-app.com/insitu-tgrg-simplified.html" style="top:0; left:0; height: 100%; width: 100%; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto; border: none" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>

  </div>

  </div>
```

into the wordpress code editor and publish, [this is what I get](http://www.insitu-app.co.uk/test-2-2/) . I want the div tag and its contents to take up 80% of the viewports vertical height. If this method isn't possible on wordpress and they're is an alternative please tell me? Many Thanks

Comment: adding `80vh` div with `padding` inside another `80vh` div is not a good idea. Either change the height of inner div to `100%` and add `box-sizing: border-box;` or remove height from parent div.

Comment: thanks the inner div now is: `<div style="height:100%; box-sizing: border-box; padding: 20px;">` let me know if not ok

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the code in `TEXT VIEW` of content editor.
Wordpress content editor generates some tags when you paste content in it.
Paste the same using `TEXT VIEW` and make sure no other text is there. It'll work fine.

In your current case extra `<code>..</code>` and `<p>...</p>` tags are being generated.

Comment: Hi, apologies but [it is in the TEXT VIEW](http://imgur.com/VM8u81m). I removed the <code>..</code> tags too, but still no change

Comment: Check the output markup on the page. Its still generating `<p>..</p>` tags around the content. around each comment you've pasted and around `<iframe>...</iframe>` tag thats limiting its height.

Comment: and please remove `height: 80vh;` from outer div

Comment: Akash K., within the inner div I've replaced `height: 80vh;` with `height: 100%;` but ive left the outer div as `height: 80vh;` because I need it to be 80% of screen height. Is this ok, recommended?

Comment: yes. its good. One more thing
height unit `vh` is still not supported by all browsers. You should research about that if you want your website to work on all browsers. :)

Comment: cool its working now - thanks. I will do some research, are you talking about before IE 9 or is it worse than that?

Comment: Please refer to this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21624014/css-are-view-height-vh-and-view-width-vw-units-widely-supported) or [caniuse](http://caniuse.com/#feat=viewport-units)