# scale and position text dynamically with screen size with css

Tags: html, css

I want to place some text over a banner on my homepage. The banner changes it's size dynamically, when I scale it in Developer-Mode. Hower I can't mange to kepp the position of the text relative to the banner and change the font-size according to the scaling factor. I tried with font-size vh, vw, % etc.

Here is the sample on jsfiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/malptek/2o3a81vp/2/

My html-code:

```
<div class="header-container clearfix">
    <!-- <div class="helper-box"></div> -->
    <h1 class="header-post-title-banner header-subimage">This is a title</h1>
    <img src="http://mesut.alptekin.de/wp-content/uploads/tmpbanner.jpg" class="header-image">
</div>
```

And css:

```
.header-container {
margin-bottom: 0;
font-size: 16px;
z-index: 1;
/* border-bottom: 1px solid #EAEAEA; */
position: relative;
width: 100%;
}

.helper-box {
z-index: 2; 
position: absolute;
margin-left: 8%;
background-color: #ababab;
margin-bottom: 0; 
width: 260px; 
height: 20%;
}

.header-subimage {     
z-index: 2;
font-size: 16px;
position: absolute;
margin-left: 8%;
margin-bottom: 0;
/*  background-color: #fff;
opacity: .5;     */     
width: 20%;     
height: 20%; 
/* width: 8em;     
height: 1.67em; */ 
}

.header-image {
z-index: 1;
margin-bottom: 0;
/* border-bottom: 1px solid #EAEAEA; */
width: 100%;
position: relative;
}

.header-post-title-banner {
/* font-size: 3vh;
font-size: 2vw; */
font-size: 150%;
text-align: center;
color: #1b6dba;
font-weight: bold;
padding-bottom: 0;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 1285px) {
.header-post-title-banner {
    font-size: 1.8em;
    text-align: center;
    color: #1b6dba;
    font-weight: bold;
    padding-bottom: 0;
 }
}
```

==================================
**UPDATE:**

well, this example is working because viewport is the same size as the banner. but you can imagine the banner being inside another big  with 1400px wide (see new example: jsfiddle.net/malptek/2o3a81vp/7). However, in this example the image is somehow not scaling according to the new  (don't know why).

Comment: All is fine, but you need CSS media queries to change text-size based on breakpoints.

Comment: Yeah. It looks fine. Only need the media queries for different devices.

Comment: well, this example is working because viewport is the same size as the banner. but you can imagine the banner being inside another big <div> with 1400px wide (see new example: https://jsfiddle.net/malptek/2o3a81vp/7/). The image is not scaling according to the new <div> (don't know why).

Answer (score 0):

Works for me with vw.

https://jsfiddle.net/abalter/2o3a81vp/3/

CSS length measurements `vw`, `vh`, and `vmin` are starting to be widely supported.

http://caniuse.com/#feat=viewport-units

I'm kind of confused by how to interpret the global browser use percentages, but, unless you are concerned about compatibility with older browsers, you can use them pretty freely.

[CSS: Are view height (vh) and view width (vw) units widely supported?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21624014/css-are-view-height-vh-and-view-width-vw-units-widely-supported)